# Laravelista Comments Pagination not working because an id is passed to the request

Tags: laravel, routes, comments

I found this comment package called laravelista comments and yes this package is a headache, First thing is you need to have a model or a value to pass on to the request, so I ended up making a post controller which only sends 1 post for which that the laravelista comment work yes and it did work I used this on my view `<a class="nav-link" href="{{route('complaints.show',['id' => 1])}}">Complaints</a>`, I tried using the paginate yes it works but when I click the second or the next button I get this url `http://cebecodev/complaints/complaints/1?page=1`. I don't know what happened its a little messed up.

PostController.php

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $post = Post::find($id);
        return view('pages.complaints')->with('post', $post);
    }
```

web.php

```
// POST
Route::get('/complaints','PostController@index')->name('complaints');
Route::get('/complaints/{id}','PostController@show')->name('complaints.show');
```

Comment: he has his own pagination, and it uses this `@isset ($perPage)
    {{ $grouped_comments->links() }}
@endisset`. I think my problem is in routes. I tried removing the `/complaints` and work. but its not good to have no `/complaints` on the url since it is just a static page.

Comment: I guess it's have same problem as yours : https://github.com/laravelista/comments/issues/108

Comment: Thank you so much! It works now!